# TypeScript Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and '...' does not exist in type 'DeepPartial<Document>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, api, mongoose

I'm trying to create a simple controller API in NodeJS using TypeScript, but I'm getting error `ts(2345)` when I'm assigning values to the model.

Here is my **user model**:

```
import mongoose, {Schema} from 'mongoose'

const userSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    login: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        match: (value: string) => /\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(value),
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

export default mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

And **controller**:

```
import User from '../models/User'
import {Request, Response} from 'express'

export class UserController {

    public addNewUser (req: Request, res: Response) {
        const {login, email, password} = req.body

                // some code

        const newUser = new User({
            // ts error:
            // Argument of type '{ login: any; email: any; 
            // password: any; date: number; }' is not assignable 
            // to parameter of type 'DeepPartial<Document>'.
            // Object literal may only specify known properties, 
            // and 'login' does not exist in type 
            // 'DeepPartial<Document>'.ts(2345)
            login,
            email,
            password,
            date: Date.now()
        })
    }
}
```

I've found a solution to get off this error:

```
const newUser = new User({          
            login,
            email,
            password,
            createdAt: Date.now(),
            ...req.body
        })
```

But I'm not sure this is a good approach and still don't know why i'm getting this ts error at all. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to declare your model like this:

```
import * as mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true }
});

// Export the model and return your IUser interface
export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Module '"mongoose"' has no default export.

Comment: You have to import it like this: import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that req.body does not define {login, email, password} and that makes them "any". TS does not like it, if you try to add "any" to an object if a specific type is needed. You could cast req to a type which contains a body object, which contains the login, email and password. Like this:

```
public addNewUser (req: UserRequest, res: Response) {...}
```

and

```
interface UserRequest {body: {login: string; email: string; password: string}}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately error still occurs: `Argument of type '{ login: string; email: string; password: string; date: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial<Document>'. (...)`